# Do we have to check anything other than DDR while buying RAM?

Tags: memory, motherboard

After going through lot of blogs, I went ahead and brought [this](http://www.ebay.in/itm/KINGSTON-4GB-DDR2-667-FSB-240-PIN-ECC-MEMORY-3-YEARS-WARRENTY-/281561945308?_trksid=p2054897.l4275) Kingston DDR2 4GB RAM. After the delivery when I tried to install it, i was unable to fit inside the ram slot.

Am I missing something here because I have like checked it 100 times that my RAM is of DDR2. Please help.

Here are pictures of the RAM. The Transcend (below, one am using, DDR2) while the Kingston is the one I ordered. So maybe I got the faulty RAM?

[image]

[image]

Comment: If it doesn't fit then the memory you have currently isn't DDR2.  We need more information.

Comment: What PC/Laptop/Motherboard do you have?

Comment: doesn't fit as "the size of the slot is bigger/smaller than the RAM's size" or as "the whole size is identical but the size of the small part of the RAM isn't the same as the size of the small part of the slot" ?

Comment: @niceman the size is almost the same but the break is not aligned

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you do not have a the correct RAM for the motherboard you have. The notch for each type of DDR is set at a different area so uses will not insert the wrong kind. Along with the DDR, DDR2, and DDR3 examples, you seem to have a FB-DIMM variant of DDR2 (Fully buffered).

[image]

EDIT: (Due to your comments and the assist Of Davis Schwarz) New image of DDR2 vs. FB-DDR DIMM:

[image]

From the Spec Sheet (And it shows "FB" on the controller - the little black box in the center of the module):

> DESCRIPTION
>
> This document describes ValueRAM’s 4GB (512M x 72-bit)
>   PC2-5300 CL5 SDRAM (Synchronous DRAM) ***“fully buffered”*** ***ECC*** “dual rank”
>   memory module. This module is based on eighteen stacked 512M x 4-bit
>   (thirty-six 256M x 4-bit) 667MHz DDR2 FBGA components. The module also
>   includes an AMB device (Advanced Memory Buffer).

From you comments

> "The size is almost the same, but the break is different"

This gives the idea that you are trying to force the wrong RAM type into the slot.

The next clue from your images is that you are introducing Fully Buffered DDR2 into a slot that only accept regular DDR2 DIMMS.

That being said, you should try and RMA the new RAM and get the appropriate type.

Answer (score 4):

You bought an [FB-DIMM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fully_Buffered_DIMM). Your motherboard takes regular DIMMs. You also need to make sure your motherboard supports 4GB modules. (Even if the motherboard supports 4GB, it may only support it as two modules.)

[image]